# Bash script print statements in functions

Tags: bash, function, shell, return

I'm trying to write a bash function that returns a value, but also has print statements. The problem is the print statements end up as a part of the return value of the function. For example:

```
function f {
  echo -n "executing f: "
  echo $(($1 + 1))
}

x=$(f 2)
echo $x
```

I want the result of `f 2` to be `3` with "executing f:" printed to the screen, but the result of `f 2` is `executing f: 3`. I understand why this happens, but I'm looking for a way to avoid it.

My question is: is this possible to do in bash? Is there some other trick for returning values or printing messages that would decouple the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can `echo` to `stderr` in function:

```
function f { echo -n "executing f: " >&2; echo $(($1 + 1)); }

$> x=$(f 2)
executing f:
$> echo $x
2
```

Comment: Hmm... this is a good idea, although if these are informative messages and not errors, a user of my script may be confused when redirecting stdout/stderr. Is there any way to redirect the return value instead, and have the command substitution only capture stderr (or another file descriptor)?

Comment: But in order for the messages to appear on stdout, 3 must be redirected to stdout. Then won't the command substitution still capture messages written to 3, since it is redirected to stdout?

Comment: Yes that's right, other descriptors will also need to be redirected to stdout/stderr